# R question. Plotting a response for distinct combinations of 2 factors. Hopefully with 'histogram' from Lattice Package

Tags: r, plot, histogram, lattice

Suppose I have a response variable (we'll call 'Y') and 2 factors (Factor A with levels A1 and A2, and Factor B with levels B1 and B2)

Can I use the 'histogram' function in the lattice package to plot the response for (A1 and B1) against the response for (A2 and B2)?

I know

> histogram(~y|FactorA*FactorB)

will plot all 4 combinations. But what if I only want those two?

Just wanted to thank everyone at this site for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to make a new variable with the four combinations and use the `subset` command.

```
FactorAB <- factor(paste(FactorA, FactorB, sep=""))
histogram(~y|FactorAB, subset=FactorAB %in% c("A1B1", "A2B2"))
```

Comment: awesome! thank you. the 'paste' and 'subset' functions are super-helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a simpler way of doing this, but here is a hack that should get you pretty near what you want.

```
# sample data
dat <- data.frame(Y=rpois(100,20),A=factor(c(rep("A1",50),rep("A2",50))),B=factor(c(rep("B1",50),rep("B2",50))))
dat$B <- sample(dat$B)

# create blank (colourless) histogram
p <- histogram(~Y|A*B,dat,col=0,border=0)
# subset and print blank panels
p[1,]
# draw data from desired panels onto blank "template"
trellis.focus("panel",1,1)
do.call("panel.histogram",trellis.panelArgs(p,1)[1:5])
trellis.focus("panel",1,2)
do.call("panel.histogram",trellis.panelArgs(p,4)[1:5])
trellis.unfocus()
```

All that is left is to change the lower strip on the upper plot. Calling `trellis.focus("strip",1,2)` will put it in focus, and some suitable other call should be able to change it, but I can't find what that would be. It may overplot however.